# How to create a lattice-type data structure in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ontology, lattice, formal-semantics

I am trying to build a lattice-type of FCA-type of data structure in Haskell where I could check if two entities have a join or not. Actually, I'm not even sure that the lattice is the right structure as it might be a bit "too much".

Here is the context. In a COBOL program analyzer, I have an ontology of data set names, files, records and fields. A data set name can have multiple file names depending on the program, a file can have multiple records and a record can have multiple fields. I'd like this hierarchy to be reflected in the Haskell data structure. But I'd like also to be able to have a relation inherited for file1 and file2 such that I can check if file1 and file2 belong to the same data set name. Actually, this relation could almost be that of "==". But it could simply be that they do have a join in dsn0, for instance.

I have other ontologies in that context that would benefit from a lattice or FCA data structure. For example, I have programs that belongs to job steps and job steps that belong to jobs. If I could easily figure out if two programs belong to the same job, that would be great. Here also, it seems like a "join" operator. Getting the extension (code) of a certain entity would be useful too.

I'm still a bit new to Haskell. I tried to look at [the Lattice library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lattices-2.0.2) but I'm not sure where to go from there, concretely. Any idea of how to get started? A small example of a lattice in Haskell would be very helpful. Thank you very much for your help (and patience).

**UPDATE**:
The Lattice might not be the best formalism for this as mentioned in the comments. I realize I might just have to use a regular class type of data structure along those lines:

```
data DSN = DSN {
    programFiles :: [ProgramFile]
    name :: String
    ddn :: DDN
}
data ProgramFile = ProgramFile {
    records :: [Record]
    name :: String
}
data Record = Record {
    fields :: [Field]
    name :: String
}
data Field = Field {
    name :: String
    order :: Int
}
```

I guess my initial intention behind using a tree/lattice/FCA type of structure is to take full advantage of the functor potential in Haskell which should lead to interesting lattice operations including geting all the extension of a concept, checking that two concepts belong to the same higher-level concept, checking equality '==' of two files through their DSN,...

Maybe a non-binary tree structure would be better? Is it easy to do that in Haskell?

Comment: To the extent I understand what you're trying to do ... It sounds like there's different sense of 'belong to'; and one entity might belong to other entities in different ways (or might belong to the same entity in multiple ways?) Then I'm not sure a lattice is the right structure -- all the 'belong to's are in the same sense. I would flatten out all the links into a relational database. A within-programming-language data structure doesn't seem the right tool for the job.

Comment: A data set can have multiple files. Can a file belong to multiple data sets? If not, do you want that constraint baked into the types, or are you willing to maintain a non-compiler-checked invariant yourself?

Comment: Thank you @DanielWagner for these really good clarifying questions. The Lattice might not be the best formalism for this, indeed. I realize I might just have to use a regular class type of data structure along those lines:
DSN = DSN {
 programFiles :: [ProgramFile]
 name :: String
 ddn :: DDN
}

data ProgramFile = ProgramFile {
 records :: [Record]
 name :: String
}
...
I guess my initial intention behind using a tree/lattice/FCA type of structure is to take full advantage of the functor potential in Haskell which should lead to interesting lattice operations.

Comment: Thank you @AntC for your comment. I replied above as both comments kind of headed the same way.

Comment: @HugolinBergier I don't think your edit or comment actually answered my clarifying questions. Could you take another stab at them? I have several specific solutions in mind, but which one is most appropriate depends on the answers to those questions.

Comment: @DanielWagner, no a program file cannot belong to multiple data sets. The same way, a program cannot belong to multiple job steps. In general, across the whole ontology we have a 1-to-many relationship, not many-to-many. So it's more of a non-binary tree structure than a lattice. Yes, I want that constraint baked into the types. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend making an abstract data type to represent one-to-many relationships. It might look something like this:

```
module OneToMany (OMRel, empty, insert, delete, source, targets) where

import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import qualified Data.Set as S

data OMRel a b = OMRel
    { oneToMany :: Map a (Set b)
    , manyToOne :: Map b a
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

empty :: OMRel a b
empty = OMRel M.empty M.empty

insert :: (Ord a, Ord b) => a -> b -> OMRel a b -> OMRel a b
insert a b (OMRel otm mto) = OMRel
    { oneToMany = M.insertWith S.union a (S.singleton b) $
        case M.lookup b mto of
            Just oldA -> M.adjust (S.delete b) oldA otm
            Nothing -> otm
    , manyToOne = M.insert b a mto
    }

delete :: (Ord a, Ord b) => a -> b -> OMRel a b -> OMRel a b
delete a b (OMRel otm mto) = OMRel (M.adjust (S.delete b) a otm) (M.delete b mto)

source :: Ord b => b -> OMRel a b -> Maybe a
source b = M.lookup b . manyToOne

targets :: Ord a => a -> OMRel a b -> Set b
targets a = M.findWithDefault S.empty a . oneToMany
```

(Of course you can flesh out the API with more efficient bulk operations like merging, bulk insert, sequential composition, etc. But this is sort of the minimal construct/consume API that gets you where you need to go.)

Then you need a couple data types to represent your various ontological entries:

```
newtype Dataset = Dataset { dataset :: String }
newtype Record = Record { record :: String }
newtype Field = Field { order :: Int }
```

From there you can use values with types like `OMRel Dataset FilePath` to represent the fact that datasets "contain" files. For querying containment equality, you can write this once and for all via the `OMRel` API above:

```
sameSource :: (Eq a, Ord b) => OMRel a b -> b -> b -> Bool
sameSource rel b b' = source b rel == source b' rel
```

(You may need an extra clause if two missing targets should be considered inequal.) Then, e.g., this can be specialized to

```
sameSource :: OMRel Dataset FilePath -> FilePath -> FilePath -> Bool
```

and friends.

You will not be able to make a `Functor` (or `Bifunctor`) instance for `OMRel` because of the `Ord` constraints. It's not clear to me that `fmap`/`bimap` make a TON of sense for this particular data structure, though. For example, if we have associations `x :: a <-> y :: b` and `x' :: a <-> y' :: b`, and `f b = f b'`, then should `fmap f` associate `f b` with `a` or `a'`? If they do turn out to have a sensible interpretation and be useful, you could either pursue the constrained-monads approach or simply offer a function named `bimap` from the `OneToMany` module with the appropriate type, but without making it an instance method.

Comment: Thank you @DanielWagner, this is perfect! I think this is exactly what I need to get started. I'm just a bit surprised that there is no standard library or built-in functions for these types of relationships. But what you provided is even better because I can customize it to my needs and fully understand it.

Comment: I can see now how the functor would not make that much sense for such data structure. Maybe that's not what I need. An example I had in mind is if we have a hierarchy of program ontologies (using OneToMany) on one hand and a hierarchy of source code reference (a partial order) on the other hand and we want to establish a functor between the two. But I need to move forward on this first to give it more thought and clarify things more. Again, great thanks!

Comment: @HugolinBergier Hackage has a data structure for [many-to-many relations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relation), and a data structure for [one-to-one relations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bimap), but it seems there is a hole indeed for many-to-one. The many-to-many structure could be used as an alternative implementation technique for `OMRel`; perhaps it would involve a little less boilerplate, though it would probably also be slightly less efficient. Perhaps you will be the person to upload a package that fills this hole!

Comment: ha! Once I get proficient in Haskell like you, maybe yes... Little question: isn't the type of insert missing an argument (or a value)? Maybe we should add '-> OMRel a b' at the end of the line?

Comment: @HugolinBergier I wouldn't be surprised if there were half a dozen small mistakes -- I typed out the whole module more or less off-the-cuff and without actually checking with the compiler that it agreed with me, let alone testing its functionality. This seems like a good place to put that legalese about NOT SUITABLE FOR ANY USE or whatever, if I knew what the right phrasing was. The real goal was to communicate an idea to a human, so I didn't bother checking if I had communicated that idea to the machine.